# Let $I$ be a minimal ideal of a ring $R$. Then, $I$ is a direct summand of $R$ if and only if $I^2\neq \{0\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Prove this statement:

> Let $I$ be a minimal ideal of a ring $R$.  Then, $I$ is direct summand of $R$ if and only if $I^2\neq \{0\}$.

(where direct summand means that we consider $I$ as a submodule of the $R$-module $R$.)

Comment: please give me a hint to start or steps to prove it

Comment: To be clear, $I$ is minimal among 2-sided ideals or is it minimal as a left ideal (which is just a submodule of $_RR$)?

Comment: @SammyBlack: actually it was not given in the quastion .. but I think it is among 2-sided ideals .

Comment: Brauer's Lemma is similar:  For $I$ a minimal left ideal of $R$, either $I^2 = 0$ or $I = Re$ for some non-zero primitive idempotent $e \in I$.

Comment: Here's one source:  http://goo.gl/j2XWi.

Comment: It is meant minimal non-zero ideal, right?

Comment: Those not defining generic "minimal ideals" to be nonzero are in the tiny minority, so that's certainly probably what was meant here. Of course when it comes to minimal *prime* ideals in particular, that bet is off...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $I$ is a minimal right ideal, then $I^2=0$ or else $I=eR$ for some idempotent $R$. In any ring with unity, $(1-e)R\oplus eR$ is possible, making it a summand.

Actually there is a sub-bit of information that's good to take away: a right ideal (of a ring with 1) is a summand iff it is of the form $eR$ for an idempotent $e$.

---

The standard proof for seeing $I^2=0$ or $I^2=I$ goes as follows. If $I^2\neq 0$, there is $a\in I$, $aI\neq 0$ (consequently $aI=I$). Choose $e\in I\setminus \{0\}$ such that $ae=a$. Notice that then $a(e^2-e)=0$, and that $e^2-e\in I$. Now we examine $(e^2-e)R$. If this were nonzero, it would be all of $I$, but then $aI=a(e^2-e)R=0$, a contradiction. Therefore $(e^2-e)R=0$, but that implies $e^2-e=0$. Thus $e^2=e\neq 0$ is a nonzero idempotent which generates $I$.

Verifying that $(1-e)R\oplus eR=R$ is very straightforward as well.

Firstly, $r=r-er+er=(1-e)r+er\in (1-e)R+eR$.

Secondly, if $x\in (1-e)R\cap eR$, then $x=er=(1-e)s$ for some $r,s\in R$. But since this implies $eer=e(1-e)s=0$, we have $0=eer=er=x$, proving that $x=0$ and that $(1-e)R\cap eR=\{0\}$.